# How to pass many parameters to a stored procedures in an optimized way?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am developing a web project in ASP.NET MVC 3 using webservice. I am using stored procedure to perform tasks like insertion or updation or other things,in a customized manner. I have more than 10 parameters to pass in SP. That consumes many lines of code. Is there any optimized way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

A Micro-ORM can make life easier when dealing with databases (directly or with stored procs).

As a starting point, take a look at Dapper: http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/

Answer (score 1):

If your stored procedure takes 10 parameters then ultimately *something* will have to add those 10 parameters to the SQL command. As @chamila_c points out an ORM can help reduce the amount of manual work you have to do assigning values to these parameters or, coming the other direction - out of the database, the ORM can 'rehydrate' your objects from the database without you needing to manually write out all that left-right-assignment.

You *could* write a helper function that takes an IEnumerable collection of objects, iterates through it doing the assignment work for you, creating new parameters and adding them to your command which would save you some repetitive lines of code. Then you would just need to send a new list of parameters to your function. But honestly this type of problem is why ORMs exist and you will get other benefits from adopting one IMO